# WPF animation to create new object and swap old one out of view

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, storyboard

I have for example a rectangle in a grid and I have a button "new" I want to make a new rectangle like the exist one and I want to make animation using c# to transfer the old rectangle to right out of View and transfer the new one from left to be on the show and I have a button back to reverse the animation and I want this animation everytime I press new and back how ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure if this is what you are looking for. The way to go with Animations is to use Storyboards. MSDN has excellent code examples for this:

Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742868.aspx

To execute your storyboard you can use Trigger. In your case would want to listen for Click events. An example can also be found in the link above (although they are using a different event).

I hope that helps you.